# PHP based games

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am wondering, when you want to make a php based games, that requires the player to wait for something, for example: I paid 100 gold to explore, and every 5 minutes I will receive loot. The exploration will ends in 30 minutes for example. I want to know, which is the best and why. Here are the options:

1. Keep record of starting time of the exploration command issued, then every time the one specific exploring player open the page, calculate everything and show the result then keep it in the database.
2. Make a cron job to calculate exploration of EVERY player currently exploring every 5 minutes and update it to database.
3. Make a cron job every 30 minutes to calculate and update everything for EVERY PLAYER, but also allow SPECIFIC PLAYER to update just like option 1.

option 3 is basically combination of option 1 and 2. Thanks for the help. I am not sure about the performance issue so I need to know from people who already had experience in this.

Comment: That depends a lot on what else the game is supposed to do. If the player receives an email every 5 minutes about the loot they gained, you obviously need some sort of regular update. If player's actions can interact with each other, this may complicate things even further. You're certainly on the right track with storing data in a way that allows you to calculate the new game state whenever it's needed. Beyond that it's impossible to say when exactly you need to refresh your state for your particular game to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just some personal opinion, might not be the best choice.

2) is more of a general approach for multiplayer game that has player interaction, but it puts constant strain on the server, which seems to be over kill as I seriously doubt your game would have complex interaction between players.

1) is probably the way to go unless your calculation is very complex and take a long time. The possible drawback is that you'll probably have trouble handling lots of simultaneous request to update. But from what you describe I don't think that'll happen.

3)This is hard to comment on because I have no idea if your calculation-time would depends on how much time it has pass since last update. If you calculation is time-indepentdent, then it's a horrible method as you spend time to update data that no one might need AND you are open to traffic spike as well.

Comment: ug...I guess you could say that? My answer was mostly pointing out a few things I notice based on your description. You should try and analyze your system when you design it and see which one is actually the best for you. I really can not give a exact suggestion unless I know everything about your system. Overall, I think [1] is the simplest way for you to go with.